# Insert a value from csv to another csv that is equal in date and hour using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So, I have this problem in my program. I have an csv file that contains this data:

```
CSV: 1
    -   --             0    100 200 300
    06/02/2017  Mon             
    07/02/2017  Tue             
    08/02/2017  Wed
```

and the other csv files contains:

```
CSV: 2
    Date        Hour    Data
    07/02/2017  200     0.1
    06/02/2017  100     2.1
    08/02/2017  300     4.1
```

What I'm trying to do is to put the value of the column `DATA` of the CSV: 2 to the CSV: 1 by using the `DATE` and `Hour` to match it.

Example output:

```
CSV: Output
-   --             0    100 200 300
06/02/2017  Mon         2.1 
07/02/2017  Tue             0.1
08/02/2017  Wed                 4.1
```

This is my code for the Csv: 1

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
date_df1 = df1["Date"]
day_df1 = df1["Day"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['-','--','0000','0100','0200','0300','0400','0500','0600'
                                        ,'0700','0800','0900','1000','1100','1200','1300'
                                        ,'1400','1500','1600','1700','1800','1900','2000'
                                        ,'2100','2200','2300'])

df2["-"] = (date_df1.values)
df2["--"] = (day_df1.values)

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['-'], keep='first')
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['--'], keep='last')

df2.to_csv('try.csv', header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

But I can't figure out how to insert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), add `0` by [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) tocolumn names and then [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) `1` - `columns`:

```
L=['0000','0100','0200','0300','0400','0500','0600'
                                        ,'0700','0800','0900','1000','1100','1200','1300'
                                        ,'1400','1500','1600','1700','1800','1900','2000'
                                        ,'2100','2200','2300']

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='Data')
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df = df.reindex_axis(L, axis=1)
print (df)
Hour        0000  0100  0200  0300  0400  0500  0600  0700  0800  0900  ...   \
Date                                                                    ...    
2017-02-06   NaN   2.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    
2017-02-07   NaN   NaN   0.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    
2017-02-08   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    

Hour        1400  1500  1600  1700  1800  1900  2000  2100  2200  2300  
Date                                                                    
2017-02-06   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
2017-02-07   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
2017-02-08   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

Also is possible add another level of `MultiIndex` by [`weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html):

```
df.index = [df.index, df.index.weekday_name]
df.index.names = ['Date','Days']
print (df)
Hour                  0000  0100  0200  0300  0400  0500  0600  0700  0800  \
Date       Days                                                              
2017-02-06 Monday      NaN   2.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
2017-02-07 Tuesday     NaN   NaN   0.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
2017-02-08 Wednesday   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

Hour                  0900  ...   1400  1500  1600  1700  1800  1900  2000  \
Date       Days             ...                                              
2017-02-06 Monday      NaN  ...    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
2017-02-07 Tuesday     NaN  ...    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
2017-02-08 Wednesday   NaN  ...    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

Hour                  2100  2200  2300  
Date       Days                         
2017-02-06 Monday      NaN   NaN   NaN  
2017-02-07 Tuesday     NaN   NaN   NaN  
2017-02-08 Wednesday   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

For write to csv use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv('try.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. How can I write the index and headers in the csv file? The output is only the data without the headers and index

Comment: try `df2.to_csv('try.csv',  encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: We got it to work but hour headers only has 4 columns which are `0000 1000 1100 1200`

Comment: interesting, for me it works perfectly. is it `df` or `df2` ? maybe typo